# Does JavaMail support Certificate Revoke check thru CRL or OCSP?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, jsse

In the latest few JavaMail versions, if want to check the Server identity of the Email Server, a JavaMail property “mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity” can be set in the code. JavaMail client will check the Email server certificate to prevent Man-In-Middle attacks.  (https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html).

My question is if there is any JavaMail property that can be set to check if the Email Server Certificate has been revoked thru CRL or OCSP support?  If not, can you suggest any way that we can do that?

Comment: JSSE can already be made to do revocation checks. See the JSSE Reference Guide. The RFC 2595 hostname checking that JavaMail does via the property you mention, which you appear to have misspelt, is on top of, and after, whatever JSSE does.

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't think I have the JavaMail property misspelled. According to the JavaMail API: "Note that if you're using the "smtps" protocol to access SMTP over SSL, all the properties would be named "mail.smtps.*". Therefore, "mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity" is the correct property to ask JavaMail perform Server Identity check according to RFC 2595.

Comment: Ah very good, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you do **not** set a specific SocketFactory, with the property `mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory` in the JavaMail Session object, then JavaMail will get the standard `com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory`, and this SocketFactory makes use of the standard TrustManager, that supports OCSP when the `ocsp.enabled` property is set to *true* (the default is *false*).

So, add this line at the beginning of your program:

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("ocsp.enabled", "true");
```